What is wrong with my Angular EventEmitter subscription via the async pipe?
The setup

In a component, I have an EventEmitter which emits upon every change of a bound Input (id)
I have defined another variable which pipes that input value into a switchMap, which then fires off a network request to resolve data about that Input ID
In the HTML template, I use an @if with an async pipe to subscribe to that other variable
Angular 18.1.0, TypeScript 5.5.3

The problem

The network request never fires
In fact, it seems the other variable is never even subscribed to
The EventEmitter does update and emit values

My code
Here is a simplified version of my code - which I have verified is plagued by the same issue (I have omitted the imports and @Component declarations for simplicity, but they are in my code).
tester.component.ts
export class Tester implements OnChanges {
  @Input() id: string;
  public id$ = new EventEmitter<string>();

  public boundToIdUpdates$ = this.id$.pipe(
    tap((id) => console.log('boundToIdUpdate$ was subscribed to for id', id)),
    switchMap((id) => of(id + ' binding'))
  );

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    // Set `id$` var to emit update on every change of the input.
    if (!!changes.id) {
      const {currentValue, previousValue} = changes.id;
      if (!!currentValue && currentValue !== previousValue) {
        this.id$.emit(currentValue);
        console.log('emitting', currentValue);
      }
    }
  }
}

tester.component.html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">Case {{ id }}</div>
  <div class="card-block">
    <div class="card-title">
      @if (boundToIdUpdates$ | async; as boundId) {
        Bound ID: {{ boundId }}
      } @else {
        No Bound ID Available
      }
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Every time, without fail, I see the following:

emitting id printed to the console
No Bound ID Available displayed in my component
The other console.log line about the subscription never prints
And in fact, if I change the .card-header line to use {{id$ | async}}, it also never displays anything

At this point I'm certain I'm missing something obvious, have found a deeper issue with Angular/RXJS, or am taking crazy pills. Help?

RxJs could be tricky. Here is what happens:
This line:
public boundToIdUpdates$ = this.id$.pipe(
    tap((id) => console.log('boundToIdUpdate$ was subscribed to for id', id)),
    switchMap((id) => of(id + ' binding'))
  );

returns AnonymousSubject. Same as a regular Subject it does not return last value to the new subscription. First ngOnChanges call happens before the view is actually initialised, which means that this.id$.emit(currentValue) emits new value before boundToIdUpdates$ | async subscription is created. So async pipe is actually missed the emission and will never get a value before the new one comes.
I am not sure why do you want to use EventEmitter as a source observable. A simple:
public id$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

should help.

Wow, thank you! A perfect answer. I never even considered that ngOnChanges could happen before the view initialization, but now that I think about it, that makes total sense. And the only reason I use EventEmitters is because Angular seems to use them everywhere in its examples! So no real reason, just force of habit.
